# Google Script addEmailReminder time different for each user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a script that will add a series of events in my Google Calendar, invite a list of people to each one, and send a reminder 5 minutes before the event using the 'addEmailReminder(minutesBefore)' method. I used two friends as a test, and although they were successfully added to the event, the notification timers were all different.

I set minutesBefore to 5, but while I (the host) got the 5 minute reminder, the other emails had notifications automatically set to 10 and 30 minutes within the event on their calendar instead of the 5 that my code calls for.

> Is this since Google likes to be smart and learn from your choices and automatically defaults to certain values?

code:

```
var addThisClass = myCalendar.createEvent(eventName, testStartTime, endTime,{guests: emailList, sendInvites: false});
addThisClass.addEmailReminder(5);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders):

`Reminders are private information, specific to an authenticated user; they are NOT shared across multiple users.`

So when you are setting the reminder via the `.addEmailReminder(5)` method, you are overriding only your private array of reminders. That's why your friends won't get any email notification.